# Как изменить кодировку MailHandler?

Tags: email, php, кодировка

Здравствуйте, форумчане. :3

Имею файлы обратной связи:

- contact.html
- forms.js
- MailHandler.php

Пишу страницу "обратная связь", используя скрипт `MailHandler`.
Ну и, собственно, в чём проблема: захожу на сайт, вписываю имя, Email, телефон и само сообщение. И что приходит на почту:

[image]

Т.е. файл `MailHandler.php` я уже перекодировал, и теперь он с кодировкой `win-1251`, поля "Имя, Email, Номер телефона, Сообщение" стали показываться нормально, но само значение (то, что я вбивал на сайте в форму) показывается некорректно, т.е. крякозябрами.

Где мне теперь менять ещё кодировку? Пробовал вроде и у `.html` файла, и у `.js` файла...
Спасибо!

Comment: @RedApple, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

> с кодировкой win-1251

Не нужно мучать дедушку. 
utf как раз создан для того, чтобы тексты отображались корректно вне зависимости от языка читателя.

```
$to = 'example@example.com';
$subject = 'Тема письма';
$message = 'Сообщение';
$headers = 'From: example@example.com'."\r\n"
.'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'."\r\n";
mail($to, '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $headers);
```

Т.е. все дело в заголовке, хитром префиксе `=?utf-8?B?` и base64.

Comment: Не получается. Видимо, я не понимаю, куда что пихать.
Мой файл MailHandler.php: https://yadi.sk/d/8cthB3gUenEZJ
Прошу либо прислать готовый файл, либо сказать точно, что куда писать, благодарю!

Comment: код следовало бы выкладывать в самом вопросе, вместо картинки. Писать за вас вряд ли кто будет

Answer (score 0):

Используйте phpmailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer